# Limiting bootstrap container-fluid width in retina display desktop / laptop

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, retina-display

I need to create a media query that will affect only to retina desktop. Using:

```
@media
    only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2),
    only screen and (min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 2),
    only screen and (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2/1),
    only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 2),
    only screen and (min-resolution: 192dpi),
    only screen and (min-resolution: 2dppx) {
    .....
    }
```

Works but it mess all the mobile css. The issue is that the design is fluid and needs to stop being fluid in 1920px < . Any ideas?
On option is to pad the container after passing the 1920 width.

Comment: How about simply give it a `max-width: 1920px; margin: 0 auto`? ... margin auto for centering

Comment: some of the background images need to be be full width, thats why I thought about the padding. main issue is to limit the media query to desktop and avoid mobile, anyway looks like the ratio conversion treats 1920 as 2560 in mac

Comment: Ok, you could pad like this: `.container-fluid { padding-left: calc((100% - 1920px) / 2); }`

Comment: Looks good and like with all my other test works with 4k and qhd but it doesnt work on apple retina, ie macbook pro.